# Java StringTokenizer and storing Array

Tags: java, arrays, object, equals, stringtokenizer

I have programmed a Worker class and the driverclass for Worker..
My working class is compiling fine and showing the desired output..
But in array and StringTokenizer I am facing the main problem... And in line **32** of **TestWorker.java** there is an error, and I donot know why is it giving
The question is...

(i)Declare an array that can store the references of up to 5 **Worker** objects constructed with the data(name,workerID and hourlyRate).

(ii)And now allow the users to enter workerID and hours repeatedly until user enter an empty string. Read these values and invoke the method **addWeekly()** on the appropriate object (by searching through the array to locate the object with the specified ID). If a nonexistent ID is entered, display an appropriate error message.

(iii)Compute and display the salary for all the workers

Please see my codes below.....

//**Worker.java**

```
public class Worker { 
        public final double bonus=100;    
        protected String name, workerID;
        protected double hourlyRate, totalHoursWorked,tax,grossSalary,netSalary;

        public Worker(){

    }
public Worker(String name, String workerID, double hourlyRate){
    this.name = name;
    this.workerID = workerID;
    this.hourlyRate = hourlyRate;

    }

public void addWeekly(double hoursWorked){
    this.totalHoursWorked = this.totalHoursWorked + hoursWorked;
    }

public double gross(){
    grossSalary = (totalHoursWorked*hourlyRate);
            if(totalHoursWorked>=150){
        grossSalary = grossSalary +100;
        }
        return  grossSalary;
        }
public double netAndTax(){
    netSalary = grossSalary;
    if(grossSalary>500){
        tax = (grossSalary - 500) *0.3;
        netSalary = (grossSalary - tax);

    }
    return netSalary;
 }
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}

public String getWorkerID(){
    return this.workerID;
}

public double getHourlyRate(){
    return this.hourlyRate;
}

public double getTotalHours(){
    return totalHoursWorked;
}

public double getGrossSalary(){
    return grossSalary;
    }

public void addToGross(double amt){
    grossSalary = grossSalary + amt;
}
public void displaySalary(){
    System.out.print("Name: " +getName() + "\nID :" + getWorkerID() 
            + "\nHourly Rate: " + getHourlyRate()+ "\nTotalHours Worked" + getTotalHours() + 
            "\nGross pay" + getGrossSalary() + "\nTax: " + netAndTax() + 
            "\nNet Pay: " + netAndTax());
}

}
```

//**TestWorker.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
public class TestWorker {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Worker e = new Worker("John Major","s123",15.0);
        e.addWeekly(45);
        e.addWeekly(40);
        e.addWeekly(32);
        e.addWeekly(38);
        e.gross();
        e.netAndTax();
        e.displaySalary();

        Worker[] worklist = new Worker[5];
        worklist[0] = new Worker("Richard Cooper","s1235",20.0);
        worklist[1] = new Worker("John Major","s1236",18.0);
        worklist[2] = new Worker("Mary Thatcher","s1237",15.0);
        worklist[3] = new Worker("David Benjamin","s1238",16.0);
        worklist[4] = new Worker("Jack Soo","s1239",25.0);

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name;
    double hourly;

    do{
        System.out.println("\n"); 
        System.out.print("Please Enter ID and hours-worked in a given week: ");
        name = input.nextLine();

        StringTokenizer string = new StringTokenizer(name,"+");
        String[] array  =new String[(string.countTokens)];
        for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){
            if(array[0].equals(worklist[0])){
            e.getName();
            e.getWorkerID();
            e.addWeekly(Double.parseDouble(array[0]));
            e.gross();
            e.displaySalary();

            }
            else if(array[0].equals(worklist[1])){
            e.getName();
            e.getWorkerID();
            e.addWeekly(Double.parseDouble(array[1]));
            e.gross();
            e.displaySalary();
            }

            else if(array[0].equals(worklist[2])){
            e.getName();
            e.getWorkerID();
            e.addWeekly(Double.parseDouble(array[2]));
            e.gross();
            e.displaySalary();
            }

            else if(array[0].equals(worklist[3])){
            e.getName();
            e.getWorkerID();
            e.addWeekly(Double.parseDouble(array[3]));
            e.gross();
            e.displaySalary();
            }

            else if(array[0].equals(worklist[4])){
            e.getName();
            e.getWorkerID();
            e.getHourlyRate();
            e.addWeekly(Double.parseDouble(array[4]));
            e.gross();
            e.displaySalary();
            }

            else{
            System.out.println("Please Enter correct information");
        }

     }

        System.out.println();
        while(string.hasMoreElements()){
            System.out.println(string.nextElement());
        }
    }
    while(name.isEmpty()==false);
    }

}
```

Comment: in line 32 of TestWorker...error = symbol cannot be found and...illegal start of type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you've specified `countTokens` as a field when it is actually a method on this line:

```
String[] array = new String[(string.countTokens)]; // Incorrect
String[] array = new String[(string.countTokens())]; // Correct
```

Now you seem to be splitting the input on a `+` sign? So you're expected input is something along the lines of `s123+12` which would mean `ID s123 worked 12 hours this week`. So in order to solve something like you probably want a loop that looks like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("\n");
System.out.print("Please Enter ID and hours-worked in a given week: ");
String enteredString = input.nextLine();

while (!enteredString.isEmpty()) {
    StringTokenizer stringtok = new StringTokenizer(enteredString, "+");
    String id = stringtok.nextToken();
    Double hours = Double.parseDouble(stringtok.nextToken());

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (worklist[i].getWorkerID().equals(id)) {
            worklist[i].addWeekly(hours);
            break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\n");
    System.out.print("Please Enter ID and hours-worked in a given week: ");
    enteredString = input.nextLine();
}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    worklist[i].gross();
    worklist[i].netAndTax();
    worklist[i].displaySalary();
}
```

Keep in mind that this is very rough and I'm not entirely clear from your instructions on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: oo, I see, my mistake...Thanks alot Recurcive, yestarday also u helped me...U r a real help....let me give it a try

Comment: i have taken some of your codes, and implement in my 1, it complies fine but, gives This error"Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
    at TestWorker2.main(TestWorker2.java:33)"

Comment: What input are you putting in?

Answer (score 0):

Why not consider [String.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) `name.split("\\+")` that will give you a string array

Comment: The question asked to use StringTokenizer

Comment: Then iterate through the StringTokenizer and populate the array first before using it